# download xlsx as httpresponsemessage

Tags: c#, angularjs, excel

I am trying to download a xlsx extension file to be encaspulated as a httpresponsemessage. The file doesn't appear for downloading, however the XHR Requests in chrome seems to contain the data.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetExcelFile(string csvdata)
{
      var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

     System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
     MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(csvdata));

      result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(encoding.GetBytes(csvdata));

      result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new    MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

       result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new        ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment"); 

       result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Data.xlsx";

       return result;
```

}

This is the api call that throws the httpresponsemessage into angularjs UI. 
Any suggestions to get this to work?.

Comment: Is this web api get method?

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that you are using web API get method to return `HttpResponseMessage` in ValuesController.cs class. ( `// GET: api/Values`)

assume that ng-click fires at your button click,
add `ng-click="TakeIT()"` as attribute in button element.

in your angular controller, bind the function to $scope as,

```js
$scope.TakeIT= function () {                        
                    window.location = 'api/Values';
                };
```

Comment: No its a POST. I inherited this method. I need to send it many parameters and query to get result.